# magento 2 namespace ending with reserved keyword

Tags: magento2, blocks, toolbar

How to overcome this ? This is my class path: app/code/vendor/module/Block/Catalog/Product/List/Toolbar.php

```
namespace vendor\module\Block\Catalog\Product\List;

class Toolbar
{...}
```

How to overcome this ? This is my class path: app/code/vendor/module/Block/Catalog/Product/List/Toolbar.php

in my Toolbar.php

namespace vendor\module\Block\Catalog\Product\List;

class Toolbar
{...}
Since the namespace cannot end with a reserved keyword "List", im unabel to use it that way. It throws : syntax error, unexpected 'List' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

How to use that the same in Magento 2

Comment: I cant edit the list folder as there are many dependencies in the naming conventions which i ve to change in many places. what s the other alternative

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error, because list is a reserved keyword in PHP and therefore cannot be used as the name of your class;

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Rename your Block to something else and you should be fine.

Like

```
namespace vendor\module\Block\Catalog\Product\MyList;

class Toolbar
{...}
```